# Have this error (name 'raw_input' is not defined)

Tags: python, python-3.x

hae....my program keeps showing *name 'raw_input' is not defined* whenever i use a raw_input.

i.e

```
input1 = raw_input('Enter your number ')
```

then the error name 'raw_input' is not defined pops up...please help fix this.
thnks

Comment: Try using `input('Enter your number ')` instead

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to read [ask], paying attention to the very first advice : "search". Just typing "raw_input is not defined" in the search bar (or in google FWIW) would have solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use `input('Enter your number ')` instead.

`raw_input()` is Python 2.x syntax.

Comment: please do not answer obvious duplicates ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input()` was renamed to `input()`

From [What’s New In Python 3.0.](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html)